# Array formula index match?

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-vlookup

Is there a way to make this formula into an actual array one? Where it would fill in everything A2:A itself?

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(INDEX('Handle Finish'!$B$2:$B$24,MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(SEARCH('Handle Finish'!$A$2:$A$24,A2:A)),0)))
```

[image]
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1S3svXvdC45VqCFu1710_VrEuo4kWo0kKe6CuxbpnqnI/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(LOWER(A2:A), 
 TEXTJOIN("|", 1, 'Handle Finish'!A2:A))), 'Handle Finish'!A2:B, 2, 0)))
```

[image: p]